# Approval Process form butttons only work Intermittently

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, form, approval

I've set up a basic leave request workflow using SharePoint designer (`hosted on SharePoint 365`) that requests approval from an employee's line manager.

When the line manager receives the email they are pointed to the approval task. They can then click on the task, taking you to the approval form with the accept, reject or cancel buttons.

**The problem** I'm having is that sometimes these buttons work, but sometimes nothing happens, a message briefly pops up saying contacting server but that's it (`the task stays unapproved`).

The name of the employee on the form sometimes disappears at this point too.

Has anyone else experienced these issues? Could it be caching issue? Sometimes when you refresh the page a number of times the form works again.

Many thanks for your help